# UIGesture recognizer override scroll view scroll gesture

Tags: cocoa-touch, uiscrollview, uigesturerecognizer

How do I cancel a scrollView's scroll when a subView's gestureRecognizer is activated?

I have a view that is a subView of a scroll view. The subView has a pan gesture recognizer. I would like to move the subview via drag without activating the scroll.

I seem to only be able to activate both gestures at once, creating an odd double translation, by enabling:

```
-(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer  {
    return YES;
```

Otherwise the scroll is dominant, and the subview will not move independently. How do I cancel the scroll view when the subView's gesture is activated?